# Targeting a sortable thats being dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I'm convinced this is a simple thing to work out if you know your way around jQuery/Javascript, obviously I don't as I can't figure out how to do it!

I have some code that used the 'this' selector to get the current thing being dragged 'div.block' 
which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tktGA/4/

However I now need to change the implementation over to a jQuery UI sortable, instead of draggable, and now 'this' targets the wrong thing, anyone any ideas on how I can target the item being dragged again ?

The new sortables converted code (so far) is here > http://jsfiddle.net/WqZ9m/11/

NOTE: It targets something else because with sortables I have to target the container's (#areaOne, #areaTwo) instead of what it used to target (.block), the block's themselves.

What should happen in the new sortables version is that when you drag a block over to the edge (the right), it scroll's to the next area, **like it currently does on the draggable code**, but because it's not targeting the .block, it does not scroll over :/

**Anyone got any ideas as to how I can target the correct block being dragged?**

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for any future reference I used `ui.helper` to target the element being dragged.